# Conditional formatting with custom formula: a block of cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight all the values in B2:D4 that are greater than the value in B7. Tried with `=or(B2>B7,C2>B7, D2>B7)` and others, but I could not get what I wanted.

[image: Data for conditional formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: `=(B2>$B$7)` as formula.

You need to use the most upper-left cell as a dynamic reference. Sheets then automatically does the dynamic mapping to all the other cells the conditional formatting should be applied to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: using the most upper-left cell as a dynamic reference.